# Reading CSS file using c#

Tags: c#, css, css-parsing

I'm bit new to C# and want to know whether the below can be achieved :

I have a CSS file in my local drive and when I run the program it should read the CSS file and should search for certain styles like "line-height" "font-size" etc and tell me that these are present in the CSS . Please give me an example code so that I can work on that

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with reading a css file? although it's best to show us what you have tried.

Comment: The way this site works is the op attempts and fails to do some code then uploads what they have tried then other people on the site suggest on what they have done wrong people don't give example only build on what the op has done

Comment: StackOverflow is not a 'give me the codez' kind of site

Comment: `mohad` 2 things can happen here ...1. either show what you have or have tried or 2. do a simple google search show some more effort on your part please

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a CSS parsing library such as [ExCSS](https://github.com/TylerBrinks/ExCSS).

E.g:

```
var parser = new Parser();
var stylesheet = parser.Parse(".someClass{color: red; background-image: url('/images/logo.png')");
var imageUrl = stylesheet.Rulesets
        .SelectMany(r => r.Declarations)
        .FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name.Equals("background-image", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        .Term.ToString(); // Finds the url('/images/logo.png') image url
```